# Send parameters to python from bash

Tags: python, bash, parameters, split

I have a bash script that calls a python script with parameters.
In the bash script, I'm reading a file that contains one row of parameters separated by ", and then calls the python script with the line I read.
My problem is that the python gets the parameters separated by the space.

The line looks like this: "param_a" "Param B" "Param C"
Code Example:

Bash Script:

```
LINE=`cat $tmp_file`
id=`python /full_path/script.py $LINE`
```

Python Script:

```
print sys.argv[1]
print sys.argv[2]
print sys.argv[3]
```

Received output:

```
"param_a"
"Param 
B"
```

Wanted output:

```
param_a
Param B
Param C
```

How can I send the parameters to the Python script the way I need?
Thanks!

Comment: no can do, since parameters aren't properly delimited in `$tmp_file`, the shell splits the parameters, python has nothing to do with that. Can you show the _exact_ contents of `$tmp_file`

Comment: Why not pass `$tmp_file` (the path) to python and open and parse the file from there?

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
id=`python /full_path/script.py $tmp_file`
```

and

```
import sys
for line in open(sys.argv[1]):
    print(line)
```

?

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the tip - but the python script needs to run manually too, meaning he needs to get 3 parameters...

Comment: @Bramat - it would be fairly easy to modify this to check the length of `sys.argv`, either to test if it is > 1 or even prompt the user to enter using `raw_input()` (since you appear to be using the old python 2).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in how bash passes the arguments. Python has nothing do to with it.

So, you have to solve all these stuff before sending it to Python, I decided to use awk and xargs for this. (but xargs is the actual MVP here.)

```
LINE=$(cat $tmp_file) 
awk -v ORS="\0" -v FPAT='"[^"]+"' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){print substr($i,2,length($i)-2)}}' <<<$LINE | 
xargs -0 python ./script.py
```

First $(..) is preferred over backticks, because it is more readable. You are making a variable after all.

`awk` only reads from stdin or a file, but you can force it to read from a variable with the <<<, also called "here string".

With `awk` I loop over all fields (as defined by the regex in the FPAT variable), and print them without the "".

The output record separator I choose is the NULL character (-v ORF='\0'), xargs will split on this character.

`xargs` will now parse the piped input by separating the arguments on NULL characters (set with -0) and execute the command given with the parsed arguments.

Note, while awk is found on most UNIX systems, I make use of FPAT which is a GNU awk extension and you might not be having GNU awk as default (for example Ubuntu), but gnu awk is usually just a `install gawk` away.

Also, the next command would be a quick and easy solution, but generally considered as unsafe, since `eval` will execute **everything** it receives.

```
eval "python ./script "$LINE
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `bash` arrays:

```
tmp_file='gash.txt'

# Set IFS to " which splits on double quotes and removes them
# Using read is preferable to using the external program cat
# read -a reads into the array called "line"
# UPPERCASE variable names are discouraged because of collisions with bash variables
IFS=\" read -ra line < "$tmp_file"

# That leaves blank and space elements in "line", 
# we create a new array called "params" without those elements
declare -a params
for((i=0; i < ${#line[@]}; i++))
do
    p="${line[i]}"
    if [[ -n "$p" && "$p" != " " ]]
    then
        params+=("$p")
    fi
done

# `backticks` are frowned upon because of poor readability
# I've called the python script "gash.py"
id=$(python ./gash.py "${params[@]}")
echo "$id"
```

`gash.py`:

```
import sys

print "1",sys.argv[1]
print "2",sys.argv[2]
print "3",sys.argv[3]
```

Gives:

```
1 param_a
2 Param B
3 Param C
```